# Is it possible to use a variable instead of a file with the gnu awk command?

Tags: shell, awk

I am new to shell scripting i was reading a script and i have not understand a function that use the gawk command.

```
  awk_egrep () {
  local pattern_string=$1

  gawk '{
    while ($0) {
      start=match($0, pattern);
      token=substr($0, start, RLENGTH);
      print token;
      $0=substr($0, start+RLENGTH);
    }
  }' pattern="$pattern_string"
}
```

when i begin reading the GNU awk manual it is written that If the program is short, it is easiest to
include it in the command that runs awk, like this:
awk ’program’ input-file1 input-file2 ...

my question : when the author is writing
 pattern="$pattern_string" 
is he using a variable instead of a file ?
when searching i found that to use a variable we can use a pipe like this 
echo "$var1" | awk.

Comment: Yes, it is variable for `awk` being defined(see all answers  in this post itself). Please do mention complete requirement of yours along with Input and expected output as IMHO your script could definitely be an easier(compare to current one which looks complex). Let us know on same.

Comment: if i have unerstand your comment you want more information about the script. i was learning shell scripting by reading the script below https://github.com/dominictarr/JSON.sh/blob/master/JSON.sh. it is used to parse json files and this function is used by the function tokenize ()

Comment: Parsing JSON with awk is not recommended these answers helped you to understand script, you could open a new thread in case you need to work with a tool which is actually meant to parse JSON.

Comment: the final purpuse is to learn shell scripting i don't have any intension to parse a JSON with awk. Thank you for the help.The function is more clear for me now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pattern="$pattern_string"` declares awk's variable `pattern` with content from bash's variable `pattern_string` (here with `$1`). awk reads here from stdin and not from a file.

Instead of

```
gawk '...' pattern="$pattern_string"
```

you can also use:

```
gawk -v pattern="$pattern_string" '...'
```

Comment: Hi Cyrus sir, Sorry if I am wrong here but though this is a variable assignment, how code is reading Input. When I tried same code in my box(Ubuntu aws one) it is simply waiting for an Input, kindly do let me know if I am missing something here sir.

Comment: I assume function `awk_egrep` is used in this way: `echo "foo" | awk_egrep "bar"`. `awk` declares variable `pattern` with `bar` and reads content from stdin, here only string `foo`.

Comment: The `-v` syntax is roughly equivalent to declaring a variable in the `BEGIN` block whereas assigning as a regular argument happens after `BEGIN`. It doesn't matter here, but the two are not exactly equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you examine in your code completely you will realize that your code will call function with an argument like:

```
 awk_egrep "some_argument"
```

Now coming onto your question on why `pattern="$pattern_string"` is being used, we could actually use directly like:

```
awk '
...........your awk code.....
' "$pattern_string"
```

This above should be good enough to make your function work, why variable is used you could see since function is expecting an argument to be passed to it while calling it and yes, it is a variable assignment for `awk`.

One more thing looks like OP didn't share complete code so there are chances that awk is reading data from standard input rather than Input_file.

Answer (score 1):

From awk man page:

> ```
>   If  a  filename on the command line has the form var=val it is treated as a variable assignment.  The variable var will be
>    assigned the value val.  (This happens after any BEGIN rule(s) have been run.)  Command line variable assignment  is  most
>    useful  for dynamically assigning values to the variables AWK uses to control how input is broken into fields and records.
>    It is also useful for controlling state if multiple passes are needed over a single data file.
> ```

So in affect, this will create an AWK variable pattern set to the value of the SHELL variable 'pattern_string' (in this case, the first argument to the 'awk_egrep' function. You can see in the code that the AWK script is using the 'pattern' variable.

In this case, this is equivalent to 'awk -v "pattern=$pattern_string"

**EDIT**

It's worthwhile to note that while the -v will set the variables in the 'BEGIN' block, the var=val argument will set the variable just before processing the next file argument. This can be used to support multi-pass, or different processing stages. For example

```
awk '{ print v, $0 }' v=1 infile v=2 infile
```

Will result in process infile twice, the first time with v=1, and the second time with v=2.